# Error in installing Python Anywhere Helper Tool

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I m begginer to Django and following tutorial from https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/ but stuck at this point .didnt find any source which help me to do same

```
pravin@pravin:~/djangogirls/mysite$ pip install --user pythonanywhere
    Collecting pythonanywhere
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/72/ea7eb1d3dc072034a90e766eadd7fe98406c8ca0664b3eeef820b7d080fb/pythonanywhere-0.0.11.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-install-DbYlRG/pythonanywhere/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
            from pathlib import Path
        ImportError: No module named pathlib

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-DbYlRG/pythonanywhere/
```

O.S : Debian 8 and Default Python Version : 2.7

Comment: The djangogirls tutorial uses python 3 that includes pathlib. I think you need to install it separately for python 2 if you can't use python 3. I believe you can install it with `pip install pathlib`

Answer (score 1):

The command you're typing isn't quite right -- you're missing the "3.6".  It should be this:

```
pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me . I have python 2.7 installed

Comment: The part of the tutorial where you're meant to run that script should be run on PythonAnywhere, not on your own machine.